# Deploy file to image library with visual studio solution

Tags: library, file, picture, solution

developing a visual Studio solution having an own picture library called Slides.
With the deployment the new picture library should contain some default files.
Is this possible and how to achieve this?

I think I've found one description:

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/23/deploy-images-in-sharepoint-2013-with-visual-studio-solution-2/

Is this the right way?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look the "Module" element of feature elements.xml.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567.aspx

Here is an example of the Elements.xml file for a module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="Module1">
<File Path="Module1\Sample.txt" Url="Module1/Sample.txt" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Can you explain why would I use this way and not mapped folders? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/03/12/deploying-files-using-mapped-folders.aspx

Comment: Mapped folder specifies the path to a physical folders in the SharePoint Foundation setup directory. So it can't be folder of the picture library. With the "url" property of module you can specifies the virtual path of the folder in which to place the files.